# How to mint assets configured in GenesisConfig

Tags: pallet, genesis

I have configured an asset in the `GenesisConfig` of my node's chain_spec as following:

```rust
        assets: AssetsConfig {
            assets: vec![(1000, root_key.clone(), true, 1)], // Genesis assets: id, owner, is_sufficient, min_balance
            metadata: vec![(1000, "Asset name".into(), "ASSET_NAME".into(), 0)], // Genesis metadata: id, name, symbol, decimals
            accounts: vec![], // Genesis accounts: id, account_id, balance
        },
```

I would like to mint this asset using pallet-assets and I am doing this:

```rust
<pallet_assets::Pallet<T> as Mutate<T::AccountId>>::mint_into(
          T::MyAssetId::get(),
          &accountId,
          amount)?;
```

but I get error

```
    Token(
        UnknownAsset,
    ),
```

How can I mint assets configured in the GenesisConfig? I was convinced that I did not need to `create` it first.

Answer (score 3):

After looking how PolkadotJS app was managing to mint the asset, I figured that I was trying to call the wrong function. I actually do need to call

```rust
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::mint())]
        pub fn mint(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            #[pallet::compact] id: T::AssetId,
            beneficiary: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
            #[pallet::compact] amount: T::Balance,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
```

which inside calls `do_mint` which eventually does the check that I was expecting (i.e. check if the asset already exists - created from GenesisConfig)

```rust
Asset::<T, I>::get(id)
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your source code?